# TailwindCSS in Vitepress

Tags: css, tailwind-css, markdown, vite, vitepress

I'm trying to get `tailwind` to work within markdown files rendered by `vitepress`. There are some sources online of how to make it work, none of which work for me.

**/docs** directory structure:

[image]

**/docs/global/inputs/primary-button.md**:

```
# primary-button

## Props

| Prop name | Description | Type  | Values | Default |
| --------- | ----------- | ----- | ------ | ------- |
| type      |             | union | -      |         |

## Slots

| Name    | Description | Bindings |
| ------- | ----------- | -------- |
| default |             |          |

---

<button class="bg-green-500">
hello world
</button>
```

the content of the button gets displayed but not the green background color.

**tailwind.config.cjs**:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,ts,vue}',
    './docs/**/*.{html,js,vue,ts,md}',
    './docs/.vitepress/**/*.{html,js,vue,ts,md}',
  ],
  theme: {...},
  plugins: [],
}
```

**/docs/.vitepress/config.ts**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitepress'
import { buildSidebarConfig } from '../../src/lib/vitepressSidebar'

// https://vitepress.dev/reference/site-config
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/docs/',
  title: 'Trinity UI Documentation',
  titleTemplate: ':title',
  lastUpdated: true,
  themeConfig: {
    // https://vitepress.dev/reference/default-theme-config
    logo: '/.vitepress/logo.ico',
    siteTitle: 'Trinity UI Docs',
    // nav: [{ text: 'Home', link: '/' }],
    sidebar: [
      {
        items: buildSidebarConfig('src/components'),
      },
    ],
    socialLinks: [
      { icon: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress' },
    ],
  },
})
```

sources for setup:

https://github.com/ky-is/vitepress-starter-tailwind/tree/main

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources

https://codybontecou.com/tailwindcss-with-vitepress.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to add 2 files:

**/docs/.vitepress/theme/custom.css**:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**/docs/.vitepress/theme/index.ts**:

```
import DefaultTheme from 'vitepress/theme'
import './custom.css'
export default DefaultTheme
```

then tailwind styles started working

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below :

##### 1. Install Tailwind CSS

```bash
$ npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
$ npx tailwindcss init
```

##### 2. Add Tailwind to your PostCSS configuration

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

##### 3. Configure your template paths

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

##### 4. Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Ref. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

Answer (score 0):

For
**3. Configure your template paths**

You will to add the **vue** files extension.

So the configuration would be:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,vue}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I noticed the html and JS extensions were not needed in vitepress.